# Html drop down: how to handle key events of select option element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have tried the below code for creating the drop down menu in html

```
<select onkeydown="func()">
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>
<option>d</option>
</select>
```

when you click on drop down menu list opens:
options are:
 a
 b
 c
 d
what i m tring is on press of backspace key the drop down should close and focus has to be set to dropdown, but i m not able to fire an event when the focus is on list item of drop down.
i would appreciate for helping me.
thank you.

Comment: check the solution!, and Modify it as per your requirements, if u need to... :)

Answer (score 1):

I have posted a complete Example,
it solves following things

> - When Drop down is open and user press **BACKSPACE** , it reset the    value(Which can b any).
> - Gives Focus back to Drop Down box

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Backspacing in a dropdown</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
       src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <p>
            When Drop Down is open and user has clicked Backspace, it goes back to selected value <br />
        </p>
    <select id="mySelectDropDown">
        <option>Boston</option>
        <option selected="true">Texas</option>
        <option>London</option>
        <option>Bolton</option>
    </select>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { // FF needs keypress, IE needs keydown
            $('select').keypress(function(event) 
               { return cancelBackspace(event) });
            $('select').keydown(function(event) 
               { return cancelBackspace(event) });
        }); // ready

        function cancelBackspace(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 8) {
                var element = document.getElementById('mySelectDropDown');
                element.value = 'London';
                 $('#mySelectDropDown').toggle();
                 $('#mySelectDropDown').focus;
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mateen you can use element.selectedIndex = 0; instead of element.value as well and set index to your selected item

Comment: Hi,thnx for reply, I checked your code, but still it does not solve my purpose, in the above code the backspace is working only when the drop down is closed, but i want the backspace to work when the drop down is listed/open.

Comment: its working dude , with and without opening dropdown... is jquery working at your end?

Comment: jquery is working at my end, but still its not working, what i m tring is: i click on dropdown, list opens with opions "Boston Texas London Bolton", now using keyboard down key i navigate to  "London", now the focus is on London, still i have not closed dropdown mind it, now i press backspace key, the drop down is supposed to close, but its not happening, plz help